# openNLP : how we can detect greeting words

Tags: nlp, opennlp

I have to detect greeting words sent to a chatbot so that my chatbot can reply in the same manner. e.g. Hi, Hi there, Hello, Good morning, etc. How to detect it and reply appropriately without using REGEX.